# Match multiple patterns in multiple files

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep

I would like to match/check multiple patterns `pattern1`, `pattern2`,... in multiple files with the same extension, say `*.ext`, such that if one of the pattern is not found across all of the files, it returns false.
Example:

file1.ext

```
this file has pattern1
with many other lines
```

file2.ext

```
this file has pattern2
with many other lines
```

In this case, since both pattern1 and pattern2 are present (though in different files), it should return true. That is, all patterns must be present across files.

One way we could do this is search for each pattern individually in all files using `grep` and check whether each `grep` returned atleast 1 match.
`grep -R 'pattern1' --include="*.ext"`
`grep -R 'pattern2' --include="*.ext"`
...
But this will be expensive since there could be a large number of files and multiple patterns to search.
Another way is to `grep` for all patterns with `|` and parse the output to check whether all patterns were found.
`grep -oR 'pattern1\|pattern2' --include="*.ext"`

Output:

```
file2.ext:pattern2
file1.ext:pattern1
```

PS: Searching for patterns in files is one of the requirement for a python script I am writing.

EDIT: Some context on what pattern means here.
Pattern is a string. It could contain special characters.
Match should happen even if `pattern` is a substring in a line. A better example of what a pattern looks like:

File:

```
move-result-object v0
invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Landroid/content/Intent;->hasExtra(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
move-result v3
const/4 v4, 0x0
if-nez v3, :cond_0
```

Pattern:

```
Landroid/content/Intent;->hasExtra
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's the second one, that is all patterns must be present across files. Edited the post.

Comment: I updated my answer. I see you asked for additional functionality in a comment under one of the answers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70174585/match-multiple-patterns-in-multiple-files/70191939#comment124058069_70174791). Please put all your requirements in your question, don't add anything in comments where it can't be formatted and can be missed.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk. But first the pattern file:

```
$ cat patterns
pattern1
pattern2
```

and then the awk:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {                     # process pattern file
    a[$0]                     # hash all patterns to a
    next
}
{                             # process the rest of the files
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)        # loop all strings
        if($i in a) {         # if string matches a string in pattern file
            print $i,FILENAME # print matched string and filename
            delete a[$i]      # remove it
        }
    for(j in a)               # continue while words strings left in a hash
        next
    exit ec=0                 # or exit once all are found
}
END {         
    if(ec=="")                # if we reach end without exiting
        exit 1                # not all strings were found
}' patterns file1 file2
```

"Output":

```
$ echo $?  # true/false as exit code: 0=all found, 1=not all found
0
```

**Edit**: After adding the `print $1,FILENAME` (and `{}`s around it) it now also prints the matched string and the file it was first matched in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This appears to be the thing I want. Instead of retuning true/false, can we return the patterns which matched? Additionally can we return the file where the pattern matched first?

Comment: Added a `print` to print the match and the name of the file it was first found in.

Comment: Hey I have edited the question. I am assuming above command works only for exact match.

Comment: Yes, only exact matches, words separated by space (tabs and newlines) to reflect the sample data you provided. Please, don't make major changes to the question. Rather just close this one and post a new question with your new and complete requirements. Leave the constantly changing requirements to the real world and jobs...

Comment: @lightBullet regarding `Instead of returning true/false, can we return the patterns which matched` - programs don't "return" anything in Unix, they print output and they exit with a status. What I think you're asking for is to **print** the patterns which match and **exit with the status** success/fail, similar to how grep behaves (except it prints the matching text, not the string to be matched). Please update your question to include that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this might be what you want (untested):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS=":" }
    NR==FNR {
        tgts[$0]
        next
    }
    {
        for ( tgt in tgts ) {
            if ( index($0,tgt) ) {
                print FILENAME, tgt
                delete tgts[tgt]
                if ( length(tgts) == 0 ) {
                    allFound = 1
                    exit
                }
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        exit !allFound
    }
' targets *.ext
```

The above assumes that:

1. You have an awk version that supports `length(array)` (most do).
2. You have a file named `targets` that lists all of the "patterns" you want to find, each on it's own line.
3. By "returns true/false" you mean "exits with a success/failure exit status".